# Interpolate certain columns' NAs based on the condition of another column using R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, zoo

Given a sample data as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(18912, 18913, 18914, 18915, 
18916, 18917, 18918, 18919, 18920, 18921, 18922, 18923), class = "Date"), 
    value1 = c(1.115668, NA, 
    1.093685, NA, 1.072135, 1.06152, 1.05101, NA, NA, 1.0201, 
    1.01, 1), value2 = c(1.015, 1.030225, NA, NA, 1.077284, 1.093443, 
    1.109845, 1.126493, NA, NA, NA, 1.195618
    )), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Let's say I need to interplote `NA`s in `value1` and `value2` but only if `date` is in the date range of `date>='2021-10-16' & date<='2021-10-20'`.

I used this code but it was apply to the whole column `value1`.

```
library(zoo)
df$value1 <- na.approx(df$value1)
```

How could I achieve that based on code above? Thanks.

Comment: So this? `na.approx(df$value1[df$date>='2021-10-16' & df$date<='2021-10-20'])`

Comment: Yes, so I should run with `df$value1[df$date>='2021-10-16' & df$date<='2021-10-20'] <- na.approx(df$value1[df$date>='2021-10-16' & df$date<='2021-10-20'])`?

Comment: I edited the question, to make it more suitable for interpolation NAs of multiple columns case. Please check.

Comment: You can just loop for multiple columns (if `na.approx` isn't vectorised. Don't remember). So something like `sapply(df[-1], function(i)na.approx(i[df$date>='2021-10-16' & df$date<='2021-10-20']))`

Comment: Do you mind to add your code as the answer of this question? @Sotos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your period and loop over the columns applying the function, i.e.

```
sapply(df[-1], function(i)zoo::na.approx(i[df$date>='2021-10-16' & df$date<='2021-10-20']))
```